# Is it possible to load Nuget V3 feed in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget-package

We're developing our own package feed in TFS 2017 on premise.

We can see the results of this feed in VS2017.

However, trying to view the feed in VS2013 results in the screen just hanging.

We have plenty of older projects that are built with VS2013 and was hoping to be able to reference the new feed in that verison of VS too.

Is this possible? If so, how can i go about making this work.

Screenshot of the package manager spinning away...

[image]

Comment: You could also get some information here: http://blog.nuget.org/20151008/NuGet-3-What-and-Why.html, it was the new version/feature from VS2015, and it really has some changes like the User Interface/UI or others, so I don't think it was a bug in VS2013, just it really has the compatibility issue because of the above changes. If you really want to use the VS2013, I think you need to create the feed VS2013 supports:)

Answer (score 0):

I checked at my side and can reproduce this issue on VS 2013, but it works on VS 2015 and VS 2017.

It should be an issue for VS 2013, I suspect it's the credential issue, VS 2013 can not verify the credentials to connect to the feed.

In this case, I suggest you use VS 2015 or VS 2017 instead of VS 2013.

**Update:**

Have submitted an issue for this problem, you can track it here : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3136555

Comment: @Darren,I have submitted the bug for this issue, please refer to below link to see the details: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3136555